# How to access 6LowPAN network simulated in cooja from outside?

Tags: simulation, iot, contiki, cooja

I implemented a 6LowPAN network simulation using `Cooja` and `Contiki`, now i want to send some commands for actuators (motes) after processing data from outside of network.

These commands will be send to motes after processing the data received from border router.

How can i access specific mote in my simulated network from outside and send to it some packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Enable remote access to the serial port of the border router node. (Right-click on the node and use "More tools...", "Serial socket (SERVER)" in the Cooja graphical interface).
2. Run a script on the host side that creates a network interface (a tunnel) over the serial port, adds IPv6 address to it, and sends IPv6 prefix to the border router.

Contiki-NG provides the `tunslip6` application for this purpose. There is also a `connect-router-cooja` make target that basically starts the `tunslip6` with default parameters.

Read the Wiki page for more information: https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Cooja:-simulating-a-border-router

Comment: In this way, i would be able to ping my network only from host (for example in instant contiki i can ping every motes). What can i do to be reachable my motes  from outside even host, for example cloud, or be able to ping my motes [globally](http://www.ipv6now.com.au/pingme.php) ?

Comment: @KavehShahhoseini The same way you would do that for any other ipv6 address. Use tunnel broker, for example https://tunnelbroker.net/ And that is a different question, which does not even belong to StackOverflow, but to a sysadmin site.